# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found:

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, data.table

Can someone please help me with solving this issue?

File Links:

```
orders <- fread("https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackerday.datascience/87/orders.csv")
orders <- orders %>% mutate(order_hour_of_day=as.numeric(order_hour_of_day), 
    eval_set=as.factor(eval_set))
```

orders$day_week_name <- 
  ifelse(orders$order_dow == 0,
         'Sunday',
         ifelse(orders$order_dow == 1,
                'Monday',
                ifelse(orders$order_dow == 2,
                       'Tuesday',
                       ifelse(orders$order_dow == 3,
                              'Wednesday',
                              ifelse(orders$order_dow == 4,
                                     'Thursday',
                                     ifelse(orders$order_dow == 5,
                                            'Friday',
                                            ifelse(orders$order_dow == 6,
                                                   'Saturday',"")))))))
orders$day_ordered <- factor(orders$day_week_name,levels = c("Sunday",
                                                             "Monday",
                                                             "Tuesday",
                                                             "Wednesday",
                                                             "Thursday",
                                                             "Friday",
                                                             "Saturday"))

The problem is when I run this code I get the following error message and no plot:

```
orders %>% filter(eval_set=='prior') %>% count_(orders,'order_number') %>%
ggplot(aes(order_number,n)) + geom_line(color='red',size=1) 

Error Message:
```

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: prior.
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: Tuesday.

Comment: I don't get an error when I run your code. Is there other code that runs between the first and second snippets of code you provided. If so, can you provide a minimal example of code that we could run which produces this error?

Comment: If you're not writing `dplyr` functions, you can just use `count` instead of `count_`. But you're already piping `orders` into `count`, so you should just do `count(order_number)`

Comment: Yes there is interim block of code between the lines. They were not relevant and hence I did not include. But here it is now.

Comment: I have added the interim code to the question blog. If I do not run the 'If..else' statement, then I do not receive the error. I dont understand what's the issue with the If..else statement